# Adding new node to Cassandra cluster

Tags: cassandra, datastax-enterprise

I have a 4 node cluster and will be adding an additional node in two days.  We aren't using vnodes.

Just wondering the best way to rebalance the cluster after I'm done.  Do I just bring the new node up and then start the nodetool move?

Or do I shut each node down, change the initial_token value for each one (using one of those generators to calculate the values for me) and then bring each node up?

I just want to know the simplest way to do this from command line.  The new node already has Cassandra installed as it was initially a non-production server, I will delete the data off of the node and change the config files accordingly for the new cluster it will now be a part of, just unsure as to the other steps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From this page [Adding or replacing single-token nodes](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/operations/opsAddRplSingleTokenNodes.html), the simplest mechanism is to start the new node with it's initial-token left empty in cassandra.yaml. This will make the cluster 'split the token range of the heaviest loaded node and position the new node there'. This won't give you a balanced cluster.

If you want a balanced cluster then you have to go through the nodetool move, node restart, nodetool cleanup procedure you mentioned.

Comment: does it mean if I have N number of node and will add another N number of node, it can be balanced?

Comment: If you are doubling the size of a cluster (without vnodes), then you can get the initial_token of each node with `nodetool ring`. If the cluster is balanced, the tokens will be evenly distributed. Divide each token range in half and assign the mid-point tokens to the new nodes. That will provide a balanced cluster of 2N nodes.